# ArrayList clearing somehow and I don't know why

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am working on world generation for my game and there is multiple worlds which Im storing with a hashmap with the key as the planet & an arraylist to store the tiles for each planet. It seems to be clearing or not setting the arraylist inside the hashmap. I decided to post this here because more eyes will definitely help. I am using slick2d so heres the code that handles the entering and leaving the planet.

```
WorldGenerator world = new WorldGenerator(25, p);
public static int worldType = 0;
public Planet planet;

HashMap<Planet, ArrayList<Tile>> worlds = new HashMap<>();

@Override
    public void enter(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) {

        System.out.println("Worlds: " + worlds.size());
        if (worlds.containsKey(planet)) {
            System.out.println("Contains key");
            worlds.get(planet).size();
            if (worlds.get(planet).isEmpty()) {

                System.out.println("ArrayList Empty");
                world.generate(worldType);
                worlds.put(planet, world.tiles);

            } else {
                System.out.println("ArrayList has tiles");
                world.tiles = worlds.get(planet);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("No key found");
            world.generate(worldType);
            worlds.put(planet, world.tiles);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void leave(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) {
        worlds.replace(planet, world.tiles); // adds changes the player makes ( block breaks, etc )
        world.clear();

    }
```

EDIT:

```
public class WorldGenerator {

    float size, height = 40;
    Player player;
    public boolean isDone;

    ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<>();



    public void generate(int type) {
        isDone = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (i > 15) {

                    Random r = new Random();
                    int rnd = 1 + r.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1);

                    if (rnd >= 8 && r.nextBoolean()) {
                        tiles.add(new TileIronOre(j * 32, i * 32));
                    } else {
                        tiles.add(new TileStone(j * 32, i * 32));
                    }

                } else if (i > 11) {
                    tiles.add(new TileDirt(j * 32, i * 32));

                } else if (i == 11) {
                    tiles.add(new TileGrass(j * 32, i * 32));
                } else {

                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(tiles.size() + " tiles");
        isDone = true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        tiles.clear();
    }
```

Comment: can you give sample input/output you tried?

Comment: Ofcourse it wont set as you are not setting it correctly.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg Can you please explain how to set it correctly?

Comment: @GautamSavaliya It adds the key first time entering the planet, after the first it sees the key but the arraylist is empty is what i got from the debugging i did

Comment: @cricket_007 editded above

Comment: @DeendayalGarg In first else condition `ArrayList has tiles` you are not putting `world.tiles` to your hashmap

Comment: Just curious, did you implement `equals` and `hashcode` for your Planet class? Otherwise using it as a key for a Hashmap probably isn't going to work

Comment: And where do you ever initialize `planet`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I didn't add anything specific to the planet class, it seemed to be finding & setting the keys correctly. Ill implement it and see if it works then

Comment: Please remove all code not directly related to the question/problem (ie most of it)

Comment: Basically, what Bohemian is trying to say here is that you could easily make a smaller project with some classes, a Hashmap with a list value, and test the same behavior. Slick2d or game generation isn't the problem

Comment: I know slick isn't the problem, thats not what im saying. The arraylist is clearing & I don't understand why, thats the problem which I clearly stated _"which Im storing with a hashmap with the key as the planet & an arraylist to store the tiles for each planet. It seems to be clearing or not setting the arraylist inside the hashmap"_ @cricket_007

Comment: I know what the question is. I'm just explaining why the question was closed. Generally, only ask about the problem (with minimal, reproducible code), don't mention or include anything else you're doing unless it needs clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem could be your Planet object is not implementing hashCode and equals methods.
Those are important for the HashMap to be able to recognize your Planet passed is same as key used.

Hope it helps.

Comment: another thing that could be too is that in your if, the one that contains (worlds.get(planet).isEmpty()), you are not checking a possible null too. For example: worlds.get(planet).isEmpty() || worlds.get(planet) == null.

Comment: But your Planet is implementing those methods (hashcode and equals)? If you are using Eclipse those can be generated and you only need to define what properties include. In your class, right button and Source -> generate hashcode and equals

Comment: Be sure to fill your planet with all properties used in those methods before to pass it to the HashMap.

Comment: Oscar helped me solve this problem without being an ass, props to him. +1